# Transform linear regression model with non-constant variance to constant variance

Tags: statistics, linear-transformations, regression, variance, linear-regression

I have the following linear regression model:

$$Y_i = \alpha + \beta x + \varepsilon_i, i=1,...,n,$$

with $E(\varepsilon_i)=0$, and with $Var(\varepsilon_i)=a_i\sigma^2$ for all i, with $a_i$ known. I want to transform the model such that the variance is constant($Var(\varepsilon_i)=\sigma^2$), and keep $E(\varepsilon_i)=0$.

I was thinking about perhaps some type of Box-Cox transformation, but to be honest I'm quite stuck. Any ideas?

Edit: I let $\tilde{Y}_i=\frac{Y_i}{\sqrt{a_i}}$, which yields a new model with the desired constant variance.

Comment: You will want to use a variable transformation, but the type totally depends on how the variance varies.  Sometimes Box-Cox works, sometime log-log transform works.

Comment: Set $\tilde Y_i = Y_i/\sqrt{a_i}$ and write out the model in terms of these new response variables. It's still a linear model, although no longer simple linear regression.

Comment: Okay, we're not given any information about how the variance varies, just that the $a_i$'s are known, but not what they actually are.

Comment: I'll try that out Hans, thanks

Comment: If I want to find the least squares estimators for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, would I then just the same procedure as for simple linear regression?